# Cordova browser error

Tags: cordova

I want to test cordova and build a simple test app.
I followed the steps from https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

Here are some outputs (no error from the previous outputs):

```
C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights>cordova platform add browser
Adding browser project...
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-browser\4.1.0\package\bin\create.bat
C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser     io.cordova.hellocordova HelloCordova""
Creating Browser project. Path: platforms\browser
Error loading cordova-browser
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for browser

C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights>cordova run browser
Error loading cordova-browser
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat""
Cleaning Browser project
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat --nobuild""
Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
CTRL + C to shut down
```

I end up  with a chrome browser opening up with an error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Did I skipped something?
How do I use the browser platform for cordova?

Thanks,
JNQ.

Edit: Here's the add command with the verbose option:

```
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
Adding browser project...
Failed to require PlatformApi instance for platform "browser". Using polyfill instead.
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-browser\4.1.0\package\bin\create.bat C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser io.cordova.hellocordova HelloCordova""
Creating Browser project. Path: platforms\browser
Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\jnq\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-browser\4.1.0\package\bin\create.bat C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser io.cordova.hellocordova HelloCordova"
Error loading cordova-browser
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in browser platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in browser platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "browser"
Installing plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" following successful platform add of browser
Found variables for "cordova-plugin-whitelist". Processing as cli_variables.
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for browser
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\version.bat""
Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\version.bat"
Finding scripts for "before_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on browser platform only.
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_install".
Install start for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" on browser.
Beginning processing of action stack for browser project...
Action stack processing complete.
Install complete for cordova-plugin-whitelist on browser.
Finding scripts for "after_plugin_install" hook from plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist on browser platform only.
No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_install".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in browser platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in browser platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "browser"
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Saving browser@4.1.0 into platforms.json
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
```

And the one for the run command:

```
C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights>cordova run browser --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_run".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Error loading cordova-browser
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in browser platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in browser platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "browser"
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat""
Cleaning Browser project
Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\build.bat"
No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\jnq\Desktop\testCordova\TestLights\platforms\browser\cordova\run.bat --nobuild""
Static file server running @ http://localhost:8000/index.html
CTRL + C to shut down
```

Edit2: Apparently I can get it to run using another port then 8000.

Comment: Try to use `cordova platform add browser --verbose` to see some error messages in adding process.

Comment: I don't really see any issue with the output :(

Comment: So It was all about blocked port? Good, wish you luck in learning Cordova :) Try out Ionic as well.

Comment: Ionic seems interesting as well, thanks for the help :)

Comment: If you have Visual Studio you could use the https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/cordova/. I find it easier than the command line stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error regarding your connexion when using the browser platform with cordova, try to use another port:
cordova run browser -- --port=8080